# in next-auth, how do you change session data?

Tags: session, next.js, next-auth

I'm using next-auth version (4.19.2).

I have an API that does this:

```
    const session = await getSession({ req });
    
    let userID = session.user.userID;
    
    console.log(userID);    //JSMITH

    //so far, so good.
    
    //do some stuff to change the userID (ie, they wanted to change their username to from JSMITH1 to JSMITH2)
    
    //now, I want to send the new value back to the client to update the session in their cookies.
```

How do I do this?
I tried this:

```
    session.user.userID = "JSMITH2";
```

but I don't think that's working.  Next time I make the API call, it seems to still think the userID is JSMITH

Is there something special I need to do to propagate the changes back to the client side?

Comment: I'm still new to nextauth, but if anyone gets here, I think this link is useful:  https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/371  See sample code from blms on 7/4/2020.

Comment: Also see example from dsavage311 in that same thread.  I haven't tried it yet, due to being temporarily pulled onto another project, but I this looks like what I need.